# Permissions and Location api's from expo are not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

The permissions and location api's functions are not working. Whenever for example I try to implement a function that belongs to Permissions like in the example below:

```
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
```

basically the askAsync function doesn't pop up when I highlight, as if either I didnt import it or it doesn't exist in the API which confusing cause I installed everything and imported everything correctly.

Heres the entire code to check:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { Permissions, Location } from "expo";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { LoadingScreen } from "./LoadingScreen";

export const MainScreen = (props) => {
  // State variables for location and error message
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
  //
  const getLocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.log("PERMISSION OT GRANTED");
    }
  };
  setLocation(Location.getCurrentPositionAsync());
  console.log(location);
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  });

  // Check for loaded status of the component
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
  });

  if (loaded) {
    return (
      <LinearGradient colors={["#d8e5f5", "#eacfe8"]} style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            height: Dimensions.get("window").height / 2,
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
          }}
          loadingEnabled={true}
          region={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }}
        />
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
  return <LoadingScreen />;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The permissions getters and requesters are moved to their specific modules instead of expo permissions API, so you need to import the Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync() now from expo-location rather than permissions API. The code and documented example can be found at this link [expo-location documentation with example](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/)